# upload video from simple form to AWS S3 Bucket

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, upload

I will be short as possible. Anyone knows how to upload a video from an HTML form directly to AWS S3?

I found a guide but I can't find the right settings to get it work.

```
<html>
  <head>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

  </head>
  <body>

  <form action="http://sigv4examplebucket.s3.amazonaws.com/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Key to upload: 
    <input type="input"  name="key" value="user/user1/${filename}" /><br />
    <input type="hidden" name="acl" value="public-read" />
    <input type="hidden" name="success_action_redirect" value="http://sigv4examplebucket.s3.amazonaws.com/successful_upload.html" />
    Content-Type: 
    <input type="input"  name="Content-Type" value="image/jpeg" /><br />
    <input type="hidden" name="x-amz-meta-uuid" value="14365123651274" /> 
    <input type="hidden" name="x-amz-server-side-encryption" value="AES256" /> 
    <input type="text"   name="X-Amz-Credential" value="AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE/20151229/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request" />
    <input type="text"   name="X-Amz-Algorithm" value="AWS4-HMAC-SHA256" />
    <input type="text"   name="X-Amz-Date" value="20151229T000000Z" />

    Tags for File: 
    <input type="input"  name="x-amz-meta-tag" value="" /><br />
    <input type="hidden" name="Policy" value='<Base64-encoded policy string>' />
    <input type="hidden" name="X-Amz-Signature" value="<signature-value>" />
    File: 
    <input type="file"   name="file" /> <br />
    <!-- The elements after this will be ignored -->
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload to Amazon S3" />
  </form>

</html>
```

I'm using Wordpress, so plugins allowed, or I will do that with html and php only.

Thanks.

Comment: didn't you post something like this earlier? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48504704/upload-video-from-html-form-to-aws-s3 - looks like a repost to me.

Comment: you shouldn't repost. You should have edited your other question instead and voted yourself to reopen it.

Comment: Are you certain your credential is being correctly encoded? I had issues in which it wasn't, which prevented the upload form from working.

Comment: Also, I did run in to issues as some of the AWS documentation is either outdated, incorrect, or using different versions of the API.

Comment: I'm going to provide an answer, I had similar problems and had to call support. It took several hours to identify some issues, and I explained that their example code was wrong as well. They said that the hash should be generated with no "\r" characters, but their example hash could only be calculated using an "\r" character.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner yes I know and sorry for that, but it was suggested to me to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I've gone through my communications with AWS regarding the guide that you and I both had issues with. In the end, they admitted there was problems with the guide and simply told me to use a different approach rather than addressing the situation in which I could never get the signature to properly calculate.

The different approach they suggested was to use the AWS SDK to generate the signature and all the form fields automatically. So here is a working version based on this guide:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/guide/service/s3-presigned-post.html

In essence, you use the AWS SDK method `PostObjectV4` using S3 connection. It returns all the form values in two arrays, which you use to populate the form. The filename is not the same as what the user uploaded, which it good in that it obfuscates the file so that they can't access it by going to the public URL, but bad in that you need to inject some AJAX to save the filename prior to the submission.

```
<?php
require('aws.phar');

try {
 $client = new \Aws\S3\S3Client([
  'version' => 'latest',
  'region' => 'us-east-1',
 ]);
 $bucket = <your_bucket_name>;

 // Set some defaults for form input fields
 $formInputs = ['acl' => 'public-read'];

 // Construct an array of conditions for policy
 $options = [
  ['acl' => 'public-read'],
  ['bucket' => $bucket],
  ['starts-with', '$key', 'test/'],
 ];

 // Optional: configure expiration time string
 $expires = '+2 hours';

 $postObject = new \Aws\S3\PostObjectV4($client,$bucket,$formInputs,$options,$expires);

 // Get attributes to set on an HTML form, e.g., action, method, enctype
 $formAttributes = $postObject->getFormAttributes();

 // Get form input fields. This will include anything set as a form input in
 // the constructor, the provided JSON policy, your AWS Access Key ID, and
 // an auth signature.
 $formInputs = $postObject->getFormInputs();

} catch (Exception $e) {
 echo "Error $e";
}

if ($formAttributes && $formInputs) {

 $file_key = 'test/file-'.time();
 $upload_acl = 'public-read';
?>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>S3 POST Form</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <form id="upload_form" action="<?php echo $formAttributes['action'];?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input type="hidden" name="X-Amz-Security-Token" value="<?php echo $formInputs['X-Amz-Security-Token'];?>">
      <input type="hidden" name="acl" value="<?php echo $upload_acl;?>">
      <input type="hidden" name="key" value="<?php echo $file_key;?>">
      <input type="hidden" name="X-Amz-Credential" value="<?php echo $formInputs['X-Amz-Credential'];?>">
      <input type="hidden" name="X-Amz-Algorithm" value="<?php echo $formInputs['X-Amz-Algorithm'];?>">
      <input type="hidden" name="X-Amz-Date" value="<?php echo $formInputs['X-Amz-Date'];?>">
      <input type="hidden" name="policy" value="<?php echo $formInputs['Policy'];?>">
      <input type="hidden" name="X-Amz-Signature" value="<?php echo $formInputs['X-Amz-Signature'];?>">
      File to upload to S3:
      <input id="upload_file" name="file" type="file">
      <br>
      <input type="submit" value="Upload File to S3">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
<?php
}
```

Comment: Ok I've found the solution. I have used my old code without SDK and I found the right settings "access key" and "policy". Thanks again, your answer was be a great hint.